# Conflict between revtex4-1, lineno and siunitx: Improper \prevdepth

Tags: siunitx, revtex, compilation-error, lineno

Compiling this MWE

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    Compilation fails
\end{document}
```

fails:

```
! Improper \prevdepth.
<recently read> \prevdepth

l.5 \begin{document}

?
```

To work around this issue, I could switch from `revtex4-1` to `article`; comment out `\linenumbers`; or remove the `siunitx` package - obviously, these are not ideal solutions. Is there a better one?

Comment: move `\linenumbers` after `\begin{document}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, thank you! I had tried `\AtBeginDocument`, but I had to move it into the document body, it seems.

Comment: The problem is that `\linenumbers` redefines `\par` and this is not really a good thing to do in the preamble. The package doesn't say explicitly to issue `\linenumbers` after `\begin{document}`, but it's how it should be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move `\linenumbers` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: `s/can/should/`